# Dotnet publish looking for dependency in Debug directory instead of Release

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-publish

I have a project `Project.Api` that references another project `Project.DomainModel`. When I build the API project for release by running

```
dotnet restore && dotnet build -c Release
```

It builds successfully. However, when I try to publish

```
 dotnet publish -c Release -o published --no-restore --no-build ./Project.Api
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(168,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "xxxx/Project.DomainModels/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Project.DomainModels.dll" because it was not found. [xxxx/Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj]
```

According to the error, it's looking for the referenced project in the `Debug` directory, but of course it won't find it there because it will be in the `Release` directory.

`Project.Api.csproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.DomainModels\Project.DomainModels.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any idea why it is looking in the Debug directory instead of Release?
Getting this on both a Mac and linux machine.

Comment: what about Build section in project properties ? What actually do you have there ?Which output location did you specify for release mode ?

Comment: On both projects the release path is `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\`. I can confirm that that's where the artefacts actually go as well.

Comment: or probably one of your references(a .dll) was added from debug directory ?

Comment: I thought so too, but this is the only ref 
 <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.DomainModels\Project.DomainModels.csproj" />
and DOmainModels has none

Comment: but what do you have actually at your `*.csproj` file at `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">` ? Or you have `Publish` ?

Comment: remove `--no-build` flag

Comment: What is the project structure? Share us the demo solution which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh removing --no-build does indeed work. Thanks for that!
I do a build right before, sure I shold not need to build again?

Comment: I think it was just some weird state that the project was in. Went to the last working  commit, redid the whole thing on a different branch and it worked :/

Comment: in my case I had neglected to add the referenced project to the solution file and that caused `dotnet build -c Release` and `dotnet publish -c Release` to pick up the debug build

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr** Create a Release publish profile with a `<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>` property and also specify the publish profile in the dotnet publish command, i.e.,

```
dotnet publish -c Release /p:PublishProfile=Release -o published --no-restore --no-build ./Project.Api
```

---

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else runs into it, I had a similar issue, and in my case, the solution was to make sure I had a Release publish profile, or create one if I did not.  The publish profile contains a LastUsedBuildConfiguration property with a value of Release, which seems to be the key issue.

Essentially, `dotnet publish -c Release` says we *will* build and then publish the Release build configuration.  When we also specify --no-build, we are saying to skip the build step.  So, we specify a build configuration to use, then tell it not to build.

Enter the LastUsedBuildConfiguration property.  This property can be set in a publish profile, or is set dynamically by MSBuild during the build step.  I haven't delved too far into the SDK, but here's what I suspect is happening.  Since we're skipping the build step, LastUsedBuildConfiguration is not being set and is therefore not available to dotnet publish.  In this case, dotnet publish assumes its [default build configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#publishing-basics), which is Debug.

To test this, I ran the following dotnet publish commands:

When I run this command, it looks in bin/Debug (no PublishProfile specified):

```
dotnet publish -c Release --no-restore --no-build
```

When I run this command, it looks in bin/Debug (PublishProfile, but no -c Release):

```
dotnet publish --no-restore --no-build /p:PublishProfile=Release
```

When I run this command, it finally looks in bin/Release (both -c Release and PublishProfile):

```
dotnet publish -c Release --no-restore --no-build /p:PublishProfile=Release
```

Only in the last case, when both -c Release and /p:PublishProfile=Release was dotnet publish using the bin/Release directory.

That sorted it for me, hope it helps someone else out as well.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is `--no-build`, with this flag you don't let to dotnet for creating project's references dll file.

UnSuccessful publish:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o published --no-restore --no-build .\App\

CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Path\App.Domain\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\App.Domain.dll' could not be found [C:\Path\App\App.csproj]
```

Successful publish:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o published --no-restore  .\App\

 App.Domain -> C:\Path\App.Domain\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\App.Domain.dll
 App -> C:\Path\App\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\App.dll
 App -> C:\Path\App\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\App.Views.dll
 App -> C:\Path\App\published\
```

Answer's sample `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.500
 Commit:    b68b931422

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview-27122-01
  Commit:  00c5c8bc40
```

Read more about [MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild), I hope this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605225/6823285) could help you to better understating dotnet build process.

Comment: Thanks Soheil, not sure if Im missing something, but right before I do `dotnet publish` I do `dotnet build -c Release`, presumably this should create the dependecy dlls (which it does and places in the Release directory). It's just that the release is not looking in that directory but rather the Debug directory.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa could you push your  codes on github?

Comment: I did and it works - thanks. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720172/dotnet-publish-looking-for-dependency-in-debug-directory-instead-of-release/53726576?noredirect=1#comment94333343_53720172. It does not really answer the root question, which is _why it is looking in the Debug directory instead of Release?_

PS the error that you get and the one that I get are not the same.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa I got it.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa, May it'is an issue in the dotnet system, do you want report that?